# Не удается создать рабочую ссылку в окне чата

Tags: javascript

Я новичок в java/javascript.
столкнулся с этой проблемой больше месяца назад с помощью chat gpt перепробовал множество различных решений ничего не помогает.
Что мне нужно сделать:
на фотографии в правой нижней части вы можете видеть то, что должно быть окном чата с 3 ссылками, которые показывают сообщения для разных идентификаторов беседы. После знака равенства вы можете увидеть содержимое сообщений, которые уже были переданы на сторону клиента из postgresql ([cntnt, jijllkm, ihkjl]), но когда я нажимаю на эти ссылки, ничего не происходит. Итак, мне нужно, чтобы эти ссылки отображали сообщения для идентификаторов разговоров на новой странице этого окна.
знаю, что это очень тривиальная проблема, но Я действительно застрял.
использовал SpringBoot и JavaScript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
<div class="chat-window" id="chatWindow">
    <span class="close-button" onclick="closeChatWindow()">&times;</span>
    <div th:if="${not #maps.isEmpty(conversationMessages)}" id="conversationMessagesContainer">
        <div th:each="conversationId, messages : ${conversationMessages}">
            <div>
                <!--Conversation ID: <span th:text="${conversationId}"></span> -->
                <div class="message-content" th:each="message : ${messages}" style="display: none" th:text="${message}"></div>
                <a href="#" onclick="showText(this)">Show Messages for Conversation ID: <span th:text="${conversationId}"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var previousContent = "";

function showText(element) {
    console.log("Showing text for conversation ID: " + element.children[0].innerText);

    var conversationId = element.children[0].innerText;
    var messagesContent = element.nextElementSibling;

    if (messagesContent) {
        var chatWindow = createChatWindow(conversationId, messagesContent.outerHTML);
        document.body.appendChild(chatWindow);
    } else {
        console.log("Error: No next sibling element found.");
    }
}

function createChatWindow(conversationId, messagesContent) {
    var chatWindow = document.createElement("div");
    chatWindow.classList.add("chat-window");

    var closeButton = document.createElement("span");
    closeButton.classList.add("close-button");
    closeButton.innerHTML = "&times;";
    closeButton.onclick = closeChatWindow;

    var content = document.createElement("div");
    content.innerHTML = "<h2>Conversation ID: " + conversationId + "</h2>" + messagesContent;

    chatWindow.appendChild(closeButton);
    chatWindow.appendChild(content);

    return chatWindow;
}
```

Comment: Во первых `href="#"` - у вас нет адреса, куда нужно осуществлять переход по клику. Если физической смены страницы быть не должно, то у вас нет обработчика события клика, который бы что то делал. Сейчас у вас просто текст, оформленный в виде ссылки. На какой адрес должна вести ссылка, допустим с **cntnt**?